# Button not firing inside div on masterpage

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I have done several webforms applications with Masterpage, but never tried this.
When my menu buttons are inside a div in the masterpage like below they do not work, but when it is outside the div it works. Can someone tell what i am doing wrong?

This first part dont work, but the second do.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div runat="server" class="header">
        <h1>SomeThing SomeThing</h1>
    </div>
    <div runat="server" class="menu">
        <asp:Button ID="BtnHome" runat="server" Text="Home" OnClick="BtnHome_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="BtnBestyrelsen" runat="server" Text="Bestyrelsen" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</form>

 EKS 2
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:Button ID="BtnHome" runat="server" Text="Home" OnClick="BtnHome_Click" />
    <div runat="server" class="header">
        <h1>SomeThing SomeThing</h1>
    </div>
    <div runat="server" class="menu">

        <asp:Button ID="BtnBestyrelsen" runat="server" Text="Bestyrelsen" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Tested both your wnippets. Both work as expected. The button fires in and outside the div...

Comment: In a file with MasterPage? The Buttons must be in the Masterpage.

Comment: Yes I did that. It worked...

Comment: It works WITHOUT my css file ??? I really dont get it....

Comment: For what it is worth: In CSS .header i have set Position to relative. If i delete that, it works...

Comment: Hmmm, very weird. Maybe there is an element overlapping that prevents clicking...